# Let's say the border and background are visible, what is the height of the visible part of the element?

Tags: html, css, web-inspector

I'm not sure how to calculate it.
I'll be very grateful for an explanation.

Which one is correct and why?

126.219px

89.219px

94px

Thank you.

Please refer to this image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2A58Y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on whether you are using the CSS box-sizing property.

When setting box-sizing as content box then this gives you gives you the default CSS box-sizing behavior. If an element has a width of 400px then the content width will be 400px wide and the padding and border width will be added to the final rendered width - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

```
body{
 box-sizing: content-box;
 width: 100%;
 border: solid #5B6DCD 10px;
 padding: 5px;
}
```

Border box - tells the browser to account for any border and padding in the values you specify for an element's width and height. If you set an element's width to 100 pixels, that 100 pixels will include any border or padding you added, and the content box will shrink to absorb that extra width. This typically makes it much easier to size elements. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

```
body{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 border: solid #5B6DCD 10px;
 padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: So by the picture I added which one is correct? 126.219px
89.219px
94px, I already looked on many websites, I don't understand it...

Comment: Based on the picture, the width is 52.19 that is what the blue box represent. The width of the content of the element. You have padding that will increase the width to 116.219  and a border thickness of 5px on each side which increases it to 126.219. If you add any content to your element it will only take up the initial width of 52.219 px.

Comment: I meant to the height which is 94px... Thank you, by your simple explanation I got it.  :)

Comment: Ahh sorry about that, but glad I could help!